# Autowiring based on method argument

Tags: java, spring

I have various protocols that my system is using. I mark an interface and provide appropriate implementations. For example `SSHprotocol` and `HttpProtocol` both implements `Protocol`. There may be multiple which I add in the future. Now I have a class as follows:-

```
class Test {
  @Autowired
  private Protocol protocol;

  public void getProtocol(String name) {
    return protocol;
  }
}
```

The `getProtocol` should return a `Protocol` object based on the `Protocol` name. In short I want Spring to Autowire the specific bean based on name parameter.
Does spring support this? I can have multiple `@Autowired` with corresponding Qualifiers. But that may make me to write 10-15 variables with corresponding Autowiring annotations. But that is too much of code making it difficult to manage. Factory may be an alternative but how will that solve my problem?

Comment: What's the *purpose* of this `getProtocol()` method? Are you trying to write some sort of adapter onto Spring?

Comment: No, I will use it for some other operations.

Answer (score 6):

You can autowire a field of a map type, like that:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Protocol> protocols;
```

Spring will then populate the map with the bean name as key and the bean instance as value. So in your getProtocol method you could just do

```
public void getProtocol(String name) {
    return protocols.get(name);
}
```

You can adjust the bean name of your beans by specifying the value on the component annotation:

```
@Component("http")
public class HttpProtocol ...
```

Comment: *"Spring will then populate the map with the bean name as key and the bean instance as value."* Wow, that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the `@Autowired` concept. The wiring, assigning the object, is done once, just after the creation of the object.

*edit: dunni's answer is definitely better, unless maybe you want to create a whitelist of protocols*

You could `@Autowired` all protocols and `case` them:

```
class Test {
  @Autowired
  private Protocol httpProtocol;

  @Autowired
  private Protocol sshProtocol;

  public void getProtocol(String name) {
    switch(name.toLowerCase()) {
      case "ssh": return sshProtocol;
      case "http": return httpProtocol;
    }
    throw new YourException("unknown protocol "+name);
  }
}
```

You would have to, of course, have all the `Protocol` implementation registered as beans with appropriate names. You could do it like that:

```
@Configuration
class ProtocolConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Protocol httpProtocol() {
        return new HttpProtocol();
    }

    @Bean
    public Protocol sshProtocol() {
        return new SSHProtocol();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the `@Qualifier` annotation, since you try to autowire beans of the same type?

Comment: In that case you need the @Qualifier annotation.

Comment: I posted an alternative way of achieving this.